# Picking the right "white" to suit a theme

Tags: color, color-theory, palette

When you take a photo of a white object, it's never actually #FFFFFF white. It will have a greenish tint if you take the photo outside, or orangeish in sunlight.

Let's say I have a theme for an app or website, with a lot of green (#379D11) and red (#B03B3B).

If I put it against pure white or gray (#DDDDDD), it looks a bit 'off' and unnatural. How might I change it to look more neutral against such a color scheme?

Comment: I would suggest the much-used approach of *experimentation*... Or google 'Find mean color in image', find the mean color of a design and add a dash of that to your white.

Comment: Could you post an image of this object you're trying to fix?

Comment: Green and Red are hard colors to work will because they are so contrasting and hard to associate anything with them that isn't Christmas. I suggest using Kuler to look at the current red or green and find the other colors based of off that one color. Possibly a cream would look good if your stuck with red or green.

Comment: May I ask what is it that bothers you with these colors? I posted a "possible duplicate" but maybe I didn't understood your real issue. Do you want a suggestion of better color matching or are you annoyed by the reflection of the 2 other colors on your neutral color? Give us more details!

Answer (score 0):

I have a short answer and a long answer:

LONG ANSWER:
1.  Convert both hex values to decimal values:

## 379D11 = RGB(55, 157, 11)

## B03B3B = RGB(176, 59, 59)

...or, if you're comfortable computing in hex, just keep the hex values.  A quick google search will provide plenty of online tools for converting.

2. Average the two RGB values (and round to integer):
   R: (55 + 176)/2 = 116,
   G: (157 + 59)/2 = 108,
   B: (11 + 59)/2 = 35,

Average = RGB(116, 108, 35)

3. Convert the above RGB average to HSV or HSL.  There are plenty of online tools, but I tend to just use the "Edit Colors" tool of plain-old-MS Paint
4. Adjust the Value or Luminosity to get the amount of whiteness that looks right to you.  You have your color.  You just need to convert back to Hex using MS Paint or your favorite online converter.

SHORT ANSWER
By the time you do all the above (it took me a little less than 10 minutes), you could probably just experiment. I tend to do both.  Use the above to get a ballpark figure, then adjust to suite my tastes from there.

Comment: My image didn't seem to take hold.  The white I got is RGB(253, 252, 247) = Hex FDFCF7